# Why does Windows 10 File Explorer not show thumbnails for mp4 video files?

Tags: windows-10, video, windows-explorer

I'm 99% sure they used to show screenshots of whatever the videos are.

Now they just show the orange traffic cone icon, which I think is because I use VLC as my media player.

[image: screenshot of photo and video thumbnails]

Why did File Explorer stop showing appropriate thumbnails for my mp4 files?

`winver` shows Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1415)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 *does* show icons for videos (on a PC I use with slightly later version than yours), *depending on the view*. If you need [to turn on that feature](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-show-thumbnail-pictures-instead-of-icon-in/7e16734a-c657-4e3a-82dd-a394769cbe00), under *View | Options | Change folder and search options*, on the *View* tab, be sure *Always show icons...* is **not** selected.

In Windows *Explorer*, choose large, medium or small icon view (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>*n*</kbd>, where *n* is *1*, *2*, or *3*). *Voila!* Thumbnails are displayed. However, in *other* views, e.g., *Details*, only icons show.

*Caveat:* If the folder has not been opened lately, and thumbnails have been cleared, it may take a few seconds to regenerate each of those images. If there are many files, you can watch the flow of icons changing to thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that I *do* see thumbnails for certain mp4 files even in this same folder. The ones that *don't* show a thumbnail are the videos that my Pixel 3 recorded (which happen to be in 4k, in case that's relevant). So maybe the problem is specific to Pixel 3 files.

Comment: Not only could the *format* of a video file prevent thumbnails (e.g., AVI and FLV do not show previews on my PC), but also files on another device (e.g., NAS or external HDD) may be very slow to show thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks, but yeah these are all on my Windows PC (no longer on Pixel 3), so that isn't the issue.

Comment: This was helpful for me: https://superuser.com/q/1730808/74576

Comment: This is not the answer. Please see the picture provided in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a just a `format` problem. It's could also be a `codec` problem.

For example. A `mp4` file can be `h264`, `h265`, `vp9`, `av1`.
In default, Windows generate thumbnail only for `h264`.
For other `codec`, user need to install following extensions in Microsoft Store.

[HEVC Video Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9nmzlz57r3t7)

[VP9 Video Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9n4d0msmp0pt)

[AV1 Video Extension](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9mvzqvxjbq9v)

Free 3rd software like `Icaros` also does the job, it supports much more `codec`.
`Icaros` also has an button call `Reset Thumbnail Filetypes`. It is useful to  reset windows thumbnail generating back to system default.

Comment: Yes, and it also applies to other formats, e.g., still images such as HEIC and video HEVC. These image formats are common to Apple products, and are being seen elsewhere. See https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/ps-heic-codec.html for downloading codecs from Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that this solution did not work (which seems to be related to corrupted thumbnails file)

I just reinstalled my Windows and came to know that my videos do not show preview anymore.

If this is your case, then the problem might be that you just installed Windows 10 ‘N’; where the ‘N’ Stands for 'non-multimedia'.

This affects the video preview inside folders, I just reinstalled to a non-‘N’ version and works perfectly.

Comment: If you do have the N version of Windows and would like to install the media codecs that allow for thumbnail generation, you can follow this guide:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/media-feature-pack-for-windows-n-8622b390-4ce6-43c9-9b42-549e5328e407

Answer (score 0):

Use K-Lite Codec Pack Mega. Just install and click next on all options.
You don't need to worry too much about the technical terms unless you understand them. If you only want to display your thumbnails, click next on all options in the installation wizard.

•https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm

Upon installing launch the app. Look at the section that says thumbnails. Make sure all of them are enabled.

All your videos across all drives, including phone USB connections, will have thumbnails.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).