# How to fix (regenerate) thumbnails for mp4 files in Windows 10 (recorded by Pixel 3)

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, windows-explorer, thumbnails

My Google Pixel 3 phone saves videos as mp4 files that have no thumbnails in Windows Explorer.

[image: Windows Explorer screenshot]

(This screenshot shows files on my PC that I'd moved via USB from the Pixel 3.)

[Here is an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11npaN4-arCjWeFyol2M-vdN6dDE9uLER/view?usp=sharing) of an mp4 from my Pixel 3.

Thumbnails *never* exist for mp4s from Pixel 3.

How can I get Windows 10 (or some free and easy program) to generate those thumbnails?

(Apparently [many](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/arpbk8/usb_file_transfer_no_thumbnails/) [other](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/lsxdvz/no_thumbnails_when_transferring_photos_via_usb/) Pixel 3 [owners](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/google-pixel-phone-photos-not-showing-up-as/82c34c60-ae4c-4526-91a8-6a733cdd8c59) report this same annoying situation; the problem isn't specific to my device.)

P.S. My original question was [Why does Windows 10 File Explorer not show thumbnails for mp4 video files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1702123/why-does-windows-10-file-explorer-not-show-thumbnails-for-mp4-video-files) before I realized that Pixel 3 is the culprit. Now what I'm asking for here is a workaround.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that Pixel 3 OS *never generates* thumbnails for videos? That you need to **re**generate ones you had at one time? That you want o import those generated by Windows OS into Pixel 3?

Comment: As I understand your question, you can't see thumbnails in Windows File Explorer. Please try to share a sample video file, so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the feedback! I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Rotem Thanks for your suggestion. In the question, I've now added a link to a video.

Comment: The problem is not reproduced in my machine. The thumbnail appears for the video from your link. The only (relatively) unusual thing I noticed is that the video codec is HEVC (H.265). You may try installing [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), and modify the default MP4 player to MPC-HC (x64 version) that comes with K-Lite installation. In case you don't like MPC-HC Media Player, use custom installation, disable file association (enable only MP4 association and maybe mark V next tot HEVC/H.264). Restore your preferred player later.

Comment: Agree @Rotem. I get _missing codec_ message and offer to buy _HEVC Video Extensions_ from the M$ Store, haha… VLC Media Player does not complain about it.

Comment: @Rotem I installed https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm , and now all of my mp4s show thumbnails! If you want to write this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Rotem You could answer here too if you want: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247471/22600

Comment: [How to Install Free HEVC Codecs on Windows 10 (for H.265 Video)](https://www.howtogeek.com/680690/how-to-install-free-hevc-codecs-on-windows-10-for-h.265-video/). *To find it in the Store, copy-paste the following address into your web browser’s address bar and press Enter: `ms-windows-store://pdp/?ProductId=9n4wgh0z6vhq_`*.

Comment: @Ryan Now that we know that the issue is related to HEVC / H.265 codec I am sure there are better answers than installing K-Lite. The [post](https://www.howtogeek.com/680690/how-to-install-free-hevc-codecs-on-windows-10-for-h.265-video/) from JosefZ comment is better than any answer I can post. I wonder why your VLC Player doesn't show the thumbnails (I guess you are using VLC for playing the video files). Maybe updating VLC Player can also solve the issue.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you!

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I installed [codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm](https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm), and now all of my mp4s show thumbnails!

(Thank you to @Rotem for this answer in [their comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1730808/how-to-fix-regenerate-thumbnails-for-mp4-files-in-windows-10-recorded-by-pixe?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2676800_1730808) above. See also their follow-up comments.)

Comment: `Icaros` does the job too.