No thumbnails for AVIF images in Windows 10 Pro 22H2 Explorer
On Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (build 19045.4780), I have the "AV1 Video Extension", "HEIF Image Extensions", "HEVC Video Extensions from the Device Manufacturer" and also "Icaros" (although the latter should not be related, it's about video thumbnails), and I still cannot see thumbnails of AVIF image files in Windows Explorer. I have multiple applications that can open them, including the native Paint, FastStone Image Viewer and others, but no thumbnails.
Any ideas?

If their 10-bit, apparently Windows 10 does not show those: https://superuser.com/questions/1702123/why-does-windows-10-file-explorer-not-show-thumbnails-for-mp4-video-files

Assuming you mean 10-bit per color, no, they're simple 8-bit per color RGBs, so 24-bit. At least that's what FastStone Image Viewer is telling me. Windows Explorer properties says it's 32-bit. So nothing special.

After many trials and errors, I found what was causing the issue. Another app (Paint.NET) had registered the association with those files and stopped working because it demanded payment (trial period was over). So I uninstalled the app and everything works fine now.
Update (read the comments below):
I had installed Paint.NET from the Windows Store. It appears that at the moment you can still download the standalone version for free, but the one from the Windows Store is paid:


AFAIK, the real Paint.NET is free, no trial version. The portable version of the app is at https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=2904

I installed the one from the Windows store. Looking at their website it looks like the standalone version is still free, odd. Thanks for the tip!

I updated my answer. You can see that the version from the Microsoft Store is paid. ‍♂️
